# Timeout-per-turn logic for a game

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, unity-game-engine, telegram-bot

I'm creating a game in telegram bot and now i already reached the "PLAYING" state. The most difficult part is the **timeout-per-turn** algorithm (for me).

Here's the breakdown:

> Game starting.. Got **4 players**
>
> The game objective is to answer the question. The question is :
>   **Mention the names of animal.**
>
> The order to answer is : Player C --> Player B --> Player D --> Player
>   A.
>
> Each player has the maximum 5 seconds to answer (can be less).
>
> Okay now, the game will begin in 3.. 2.. 1.. GO!!
>
> Player C answer: **dog** (1 sec)
>
> Player B answer : **cat** (1 sec)
>
> Player D answer : **deer** (1 sec)
>
> Player A answer : **bird** (2 sec)
>
> And when it goes back to Player C, it will be 5 secs, and my logic is
>   to check whether the oldTurnId (Player C) === currentTurnId (Player
>   C). In this case, player C will get notified that the time is out, and he will be sent off, but
>   player C is about to answer for the 2nd time.

`I have this columns on my table : previousTurnId, currentTurnId, nextTurnId`.

But i can't find any direction to tackle this problem.

FYI, I'm using node.js to create this game and the main part is I'm using setTimeOut a lot for this timeout-per-turn logic.

Anyone has better idea for tackling this problem?

Thanks a lot guys,
All help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is a [clearTimeout](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_cleartimeout_timeout). Basically, you would clear the timeout if the player answers within the next five seconds, otherwise, you carry on with kicking the player out of the game as normal. You can get the timeout ID as a return value from `setTimeout`.

I'm making an assumption on your code, but this would basically be how it would go:

```
var playerTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
  removePlayer(player);
  startNextPlayersTurn();
}, 5000);

player.on('answer', function() {
  clearTimeout(playerTimeout);
  startNextPlayersTurn();
});
```

Comment: Ahhhh, some of bright idea, i dont even know about that thing. Anyway, thanks dude. Will try it later, and will update the result. Thanks!!

Comment: Do you mean passing a parameter to the function called by `setTimeout` after the timeout? You can just wrap the `setTimeout` in a function `function startPlayerTimeout(player) { return setTimeout(function() { removePlayer(player); }, 5000); }`

Comment: okay, but if i wrap it, i can't use the clearTimeout function from outside right?

Comment: You can - remember `setTimeout` returns a `Timeout` object. The return value of your wrapper function, `startPlayerTimeout` can be passed to `clearTimeout` to clear it.

Comment: once again, you taught me the fundamental things. thanks man, stackoverflow need more people like you :). And i've checked your answer as accepted although I haven't tested it yet. But the idea is great and i know it will work. Thanks man!

Comment: hi man, do you have any idea, how to clear timeout for previous instance or something? for example, the game already finished, and i want to cleartimeout from previous game, can i store the timeoutid for example to the database?