# Node JS - clearTimeout from previous instance or state

Tags: javascript, node.js, instance, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm working on a telegram bot project that has a lot to do with setTimeout. And currently my problem is, I can't clear the timeout, even if i already put it on `module.exports`.

Here's my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40695902/timeout-per-turn-logic-for-a-game/40697789?noredirect=1#comment68629243_40697789).

The problem is, whenever I clear the timeout, it does nothing. The timeout still goes on.

Here's my code to create the timeout

```
var createSingleton = require('create-singleton');

var p3 = createSingleton(function mySingleton() {
  service.canceledTimeout(res,bot)
});

var myInstance3 = new p3();
```

I got a module called promises

```
module.exports.timeouts = []; //general.timeouts
```

And i put the setTimeout object to that module

```
canceledTimeout = function(res,bot) {
    return general.timeouts.push(setTimeout(function () {
        return updateState(general.THIRTY_SECONDS_REMAINING_CHECK_STATE, res)
        .then (function(msg) {
            if (msg !== null) {
            return bot.sendMessage(res.chat.id, msg, general.baseFormat())
            .then (function(x) {

                setTimeout(function () {
                updateState(general.TIMEOUT, res)
                .then (function(msg) {
                    if (msg !== null) {
                    return bot.sendMessage(res.chat.id, msg, general.baseFormat());
                    }
                });
                },30000);

            });             
            }
        });
        },90000));
}
```

Whenever the game/room is finished, I call this function.

```
clearTimeout(general.timeouts);
```

**But**, after the player created a room again, the timeout still runs.

I think the problem is the timeout is not being cleared. That's from my point of view.

Any thought or help will be appreciated guys.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see at least two issues:

1. There are **two** `setTimeout` calls there, and you're not remembering the handle of one of them. If you don't want to cancel that second 30-second timer, that's fine, but I thought I should call it out.
2. `clearTimeout` accepts **a single timer handle**, but you're passing it an array here:

   ```
   clearTimeout(general.timeouts);
   ```

   Instead, you need to clear them individually:

   ```
   general.timeouts.forEach(function(handle) { clearTimeout(handle) });
   ```

   (Subject to testing that the extra args it receives don't bother it, you may be able to shorten that to `general.timeouts.forEach(clearTimeout);`. But again, `forEach` calls its callback with three args, not just one, so be sure to test before using that.)

Comment: hi man, thanks. will check it first, and will update the result . cheers

Comment: mann, seriously? you cured my headache just now! I added the second timeout to the array too. Thanks for spending your time to help me. I appreciate it, marked!

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code source.

First, you have two timer in your function:
setTimeout(..., 90000)
and
setTimeout(..., 30000)

Second, you cannot pass an array into clearTimeout method. It has no effect.
If you want to clear timer in an array, you have to clear them one by one, example:

```
var timeouts = [timer1, timer2, timer3];
//loop through the array and clear them one by one
for (var i = 0; i < timeouts.length; i++) {
    clearTimeout(timeouts[i]);
}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing the problem out man, and yeah, thats the problem actually. Thanks